# How to fix missing font(s) affecting friendly-recovery menu screen appearance?

Tags: debian, grub2, fonts

Test installs of Debian 12 where I've installed `friendly-recovery` sometimes look like this:

[image]

instead of having a nice ASCII box drawn around the menu.

Some of the test installs don't look like this - they show the nice box -, but I have been unable to isolate the difference.

Am I missing a font, or something else? How to get the nice box around the menu?

Comment: It's not the font (though that could be an additional problem), but the screenshot shows that output is in UTF-8 on a device that's not initialized to display UTF-8.

Comment: @ThomasDickey is there a way to fix that?

Comment: As I recall it, friendly-recovery is executed before completely booting, so that would be a bug in it (I'd go that route - report it as a bug - if it's not, the package maintainer should explain how to work around it).